# Why can't I summon the Wall of Flesh?

Tags: terraria

I started a new world and I went to the underworld to fight the Wall of Flesh, but when I dropped the Guide's doll into the lava, it didn't summon the Wall of Flesh. I checked the map to see if the Guide is dead or something, but he isn't. I did it again and I stood near the lava, so it is easy to understand if it went into the lava, but nothing happened.

Can you guys explain what is going on and let me know if you experienced this as well?

Comment: See the [Wiki page](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Flesh) for more information. You appear to be doing everything necessary as far as I can tell so perhaps your game is glitched. The message "Guide was Slain" must appear.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Comment: @FluidizedPigeonReactor prior to my edit, the question body needed some improvement.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: You didn't drop the doll into the lava.

Comment: I am near the lava then i threw it

Answer (score 6):

I see two possibilities:

- You were not in the Underworld (where you see the background with the rivers of lava). Dropping the doll into lava in higher layers does not work.
- You think you threw the doll but you actually tried to *use* it by selecting it on the hotbar or picking it up and then right-clicking. *Throwing* is a different action (usually on the 't' key). If you see the doll fly into the lava and it's gone from your inventory, then you threw it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're actually dropping the guide doll into lava that is deeper than 1/2 a tile.

Comment: Yes, I dropped the doll In the lava right next to me. I tried multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If the doll isn't working for you, you could also try the Guide himself; as of recent updates throwing him into the lava of the Underworld also summons the WoF.

To transport him down there, you could do a rehousing trick by making valid housing in the Underworld and destroying the Guide's valid housing aboveground. At night, the Guide will teleport into the house and you can simply build a chasm for him to fall into the lava.